# Is it possible to merge static frameworks into dynamic one

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks

I have two static frameworks written in objective-c. I want to merge them into dynamic framework(Swift). I've created dynamic framework, linked these static frameworks and I'm able to use their classes.

I've created application and embedded dynamic framework. I also added flag -all_load to Other Linker Flags and I'm able to use dynamic framework API.

When I remove static framework(dynamic framework dependency) then app doesn't compile throwing error: Missing required module.

I want to hide static frameworks and ship dynamic framework without static frameworks bundles.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

May not be the only issue, but for sure your app needs to add search paths for static libraries inside your dynamic library:

1. locate your framework in the project. It will be something like `$(SRCROOT)/.../YourFramework.framework`
2. Inside it, locate the static frameworks. Typically `.../YourFramework.framework/SupportModules`
3. Go to app's target Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Search Paths > Import Paths, and add above path as `$(SRCROOT)/.../YourFramework.framework/SupportModules/**`, and set Recursive to `true`.

Check [this](https://medium.com/john-lewis-software-engineering/adding-a-third-party-framework-inside-a-first-party-framework-in-xcode-3ba58cfd08da) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/95631) for more tips.

Comment: Is it necessary to have static frameworks inside dynamic framework folder? I don't want anyone to see my static frameworks

Comment: where the target app will take them from if you don't bundle them in?